# Multiple gsub() expressions in R

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to clean a column of data from a data frame with many gsub commands.

Some examples would be:

```
df$col1<-gsub("-00070", "-0070", df$col1)
df$col1<-gsub("-00063", "-0063",df$col1)
df$col1<-gsub("F4", "FA", df$col1)
...
```

Looking at the column after running these lines of code, it looks like some of the changes have taken, but some have not.  Moreover, if I run the block of code with the gsub() commands more changes start taking effect the more I run the block.
I'm very confused by this behavior, any information is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example of what you're seeing.

Comment: If you want any help, please provide some sample text and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a better way, but you could always use `Map`

```
new <- 1:3
old <- letters[1:3]

to.change <- letters[1:10]

Map(function(x, y) to.change <<- gsub(x, y, to.change), old, new)

to.change

#  [1] "1" "2" "3" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"
```